# AngularJs :Expand and collapse in directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code :

```
<div >
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <li class="" >      
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{filter.year}}">
            {{filter.year}}         
            </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse{{filter.year}}">
        <li><a href="#">January</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like that when I click the years the second show the data...

But it doesn't work

Comment: Tool late to reply. Might be helpful for some one. Have a look at this tutorial. http://www.aneejian.com/angular-js-custom-directive-expand-collapse/

Answer (score 1):

Try [ng-href](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) instead:

Quoted from the doc:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use angularui toggle collapse (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). In the outer ul set ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" and in the inner ul set collapse="isCollapsed".

```
    module.directive('collapseDirective', function(){
      return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          transclude: 'true',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.isCollapsed = true;
          };
        }
    });

<div collapse-directive>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <li>      
        <a ng-click={isCollapsed=!isCollapsed} class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{filter.year}}">
            {{filter.year}}         
            </a>
    <ul collapse=isCollapsed class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse{{filter.year}}">
        <li><a href="#">January</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add relevant code to your answer. Link only answers are considered bad practice on SO.